# Is it possible to get SPGroup's Web application Name Directly using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, groups, web-application, sharepoint-farm

I'm trying to get The name of the The **content_Db** (WebApp) where a specific group lives.

I've been trying to get these info by looking into the SqlDb. but I only could find Site ID reference.

is there any way workaround to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You either open the Central Admin to find the Database Details.

Or you can use below PowerShell script.

```
Get-SPContentDatabase -site http://siteurl
```

Answer (score 0):

it is [unsupported to query SharePoint’s databases directly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057/en-us) and should not be done in production without the direct involvement of a Microsoft support engineer.Every Content DB has a User info table which contains the user information.

Groups are stored in the same content database where the site Collection reside.So, Once you get the site collection DB name that is what you need.

If you run the below powershell, it will list all the content database with list of site collection.

```
Get-SPContentDatabase | %{Write-Output "- $($_.Name)”; foreach($site in $_.sites){write-Output $site.url}} > C:\sitecollections.txt
```

http://sharepointrelated.com/2012/03/09/get-site-collections-per-content-database-one-liner/